# Invalid string offset errors when compiling RaspiCam C++ Library

Tags: raspicam, c++, software-compilation

I am getting these warnings with the RaspiCam C++ library, and wondering if anyone has a fix for them? My program is also crashing and I'm wondering if it's related.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: invalid string offset 4558 >= 4040 for section `.strtab'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: invalid string offset 4543 >= 4040 for section `.strtab'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: invalid string offset 4531 >= 4040 for section `.strtab'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: invalid string offset 4569 >= 4040 for section `.strtab'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: invalid string offset 4577 >= 4040 for section `.strtab'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: invalid string offset 4524 >= 4040 for section `.strtab'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libraspicam_cv.so: invalid string offset 4557 >= 4040 for section `.strtab'
```

The way I compile is:
`cd raspicam
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..`

Version 0.1.6 and 0.1.3 both do this for me. Version 0.1.2 from [github](https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam%20github) does not but then my program immediately segfaults when I try running it. [This issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspicam/tickets/21/) said that 0.1.3 would work but it did not.

Comment: You should mention how you compiled the `.so`.

Comment: I ended up just using the V4L2 library instead of RaspiCam, and it's working pretty well except for the video resolution errors, but those have a promising fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390810/opencv-cant-set-resolution-of-video-capture

Comment: `cmake` doesn't compile anything, it just generates makefiles.

Comment: Er right, then make / sudo make install / sudo ldconfig